# Error trying to typeset array

Tags: equations

I am trying to typeset the following `array`:

```
\begin{gather*}
\begin{array}
$(u_{n+k})- (u_{n})$ & =\sum\limits_{p=1}^{p=k} \dfrac{1}{(n+p)!}$ \\
& $\preceq \dfrac{1}{n!} (\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\sum\limits_{p=1}^{p=k-1} \dfrac{1}{(n+p)(n+p+1)}) $\\
& $= \dfrac{1}{n!} (\dfrac{1}{n+1}+\sum\limits_{p=1}^{p=k-1} \dfrac{1}{n+p}-\dfrac{1}{n+p+1}}) $\\
& $= \dfrac{1}{n!} (\dfrac{1}{n+1}+(\dfrac{1}{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{n+k}))$ \\
& $\preceq \dfrac{1}{n!}.\dfrac{2}{n+1}$ \\
& $= \varepsilon$
\end{array}
```

This is the error report:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.617 $
(u_{n+k})- (u_{n})$ & =\sum\limits_{p=1}^{p=k} \dfrac{1}{(n+p)!}$ \\
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! LaTeX Error: Illegal character in array arg.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
```

And this is the output that I would like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Also, if you can, please make your code compilable, or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: give me axample , i'm beginner i try to prepare a pdf to student of maths ... any help

Comment: A LaTeX document always consists of a `\documentclass{}`, and it usually also has a preamble, which is for, among other things, loading packages that you need in your document.

Comment: i use : \\
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to start math mode inside of the array. You should switch into math mode outside of the array. Put either `$` or `\[` before and after it, depending on whether you want inline math or display math. You also have an extra brace `}` in the fourth line.

Comment: You can edit your question, rather than posting it as a comment, but it would also be best to make the preamble as minimal as possible. Just enough that's needed to reproduce the problem. This is called a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: But anyway, if you put `$` before `\begin{array}` and `$` after `\end{array}`, take out all of the `$` inside of the `array` environment, and remove the extra `}` in the fourth line, your example compiles just fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

- I don't think you want an `array` environment inside a `gather*` environment; a single `align*` environment will do fine. Note that because `align*` typesets its material in displaymath mode, you should not provide `$` (math mode) switches at the start and end of each row.
- Do take care to enlarge parentheses when they surround material such as fractions and large summation signs. However, `\left(` and `\right)` can easily end up creating parentheses that are too large (typographically speaking). In the code below, I deliberately use explicit sizing instructions for the parentheses rather than `\left` and `\right`.
- I've also inserted an additional pair of parentheses to enclose some of the material in row 3.
- I've replaced two instances of `\preceq` with `\le` ("less than or equal to").
- All instances of `\dfrac` could be replaced with `\frac` because the material in an `align*` environment is in displaymath mode by default. Similarly, it's not necessary to write `\sum\limits` while in displaymath mode.
- I would not repeat the summation index in the superscript part, i.e., I suggest you write `\sum_{p=1}^{k}` instead of `\sum_{p=1}^{p=k}`.
- The parentheses around the terms `u_{n+k}` and `u_{n}` in the first row don't appear in the screenshot and should be omitted. The "dot" ("period") in the second-to-last row seems out of place and should be replaced with either a thinspace or a `\cdot` directive.
- Optional: If you judge the space between the two large closing parentheses (created via `\Bigr)\biggr)`) to be a bit too generous, you could write `\Bigr)\!\biggr)`, i.e., insert a negative thinspace directive, to address this issue.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' environment
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
u_{n+k}- u_{n} 
&=\sum_{p=1}^{k} \frac{1}{(n+p)!} \\
&\le \frac{1}{n!} \biggl(\frac{1}{n+1}+\sum\limits_{p=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{(n+p)(n+p+1)}\biggr) \\
&= \frac{1}{n!} \biggl(\frac{1}{n+1}+\sum_{p=1}^{k-1} \Bigl(\frac{1}{n+p}-\frac{1}{n+p+1}\Bigr)\biggr) \\
&= \frac{1}{n!} \biggl(\frac{1}{n+1}+\Bigl(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+k}\Bigr)\biggr) \\
&\le \frac{1}{n!} \, \frac{2}{n+1} \\
&= \varepsilon
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great Mr @Mico i'm so thankful for you and Adam

Comment: i'll but i need 15 reputation, for all thank you very much :D

Comment: Why the parentheses in `(u_{n+k})-(u_n)`? They might suggest a wrong meaning (the sequence instead of the term). The original hasn't them (and it was probably typeset with `eqnarray`, */shocked*).

Comment: @egreg - The parentheses were in the code provided by the OP (though not in the screenshot), and I hadn't noticed them (shocking!). I'll post an updated version without those unnecessary parentheses.